# Robocode instadd issue in windows 7 for .Net platform

Tags: .net, windows, robocode

I want developing the robocode base on .Net platform, but I meet a issue to starting it.

I had installed Java and .Net 4.0 on my machine. After download and installed the robocode-1.7.4.4-setup.jar, the robocode application can working well.

But when I try to developing robot following this article http://robowiki.net/wiki/Robocode/.NET/Create_a_.NET_robot_with_Visual_Studio, when I want add the reference to project, it can't find any dll file in the libs folder. It seems lacks the robocode.dotnet-xxxx-setup.jar file.

I don't know how to fix this issue, anybody help me?

Comment: The file type is jar in the libs folder, so did I download the wrong robocode source code?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed the robocode .NET plug-in (robocode.dotnet-1.8.0.0-setup.jar) as well as the robocde-1.8.0.0-setup.jar file.